# Objectify filter not working after adding @index to fields

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filter, objectify

I'm trying to get a filtered list from the data store using Objectify, but keep getting an empty list back. I tried adding @index and also creating a datastore-index.xml file, but still get undefined back.

My Listing class:

```
@Entity
@Index
public class Listing {
    @Id private Long id;
    @Index private double price;
```

...

My Api:

```
@Api(name ="xxxx")
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class ListingServiceAPI {

    @ApiMethod(name = "getListings")
    public List<Listing> getListings() {
        return ofy().load().type(Listing.class).filter("price >", 15).list(); //this fails

        //return ofy().load().type(Listing.class).limit(3).list(); //this works
    }
}
```

datastore-indexes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
  <datastore-index kind="Listing" ancestor="false">
    <property name="price" direction="asc" />
    <property name="category" direction="asc" />
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Anybody know how to fix this to get the filter query to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made a property indexed after the data was already stored in the Datastore, your queries will continue to come up empty. This happens because the App Engine indexes all entities as they are saved. You will have to re-save all entities after making changes to the list of indexed properties.

Comment: Thanks! this got it to display the new data, but now it just returns all the new ones, rather than just those > 15. Do you know what could be wrong there?  [Edit] I changed it to 15.0 and it worked. Doh!

Comment: Yes, you have to be careful with the type of data. If you store Doubles, then you should use a double in your filter.